# Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'RouterModule' declared by the module 'AppRoutingModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, router

Hello fellow programmer friends,

Need help for the error in the title.

This is my routing module code

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I tried removing RouterModule from the declarations array as well but not getting rectified.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

In declarations you can not add any Modules. As the error says: only Components,Pipes or Directives are allowed to be declared in declarations array

Answer (score 3):

Understood what mistake I did.

I placed the RouterModule in declarations instead of exports.

This thread may assist future learners who make the same mistake like me.

Comment: However not able to relate the error message with the error made.

Answer (score 1):

Add `RouterTestingModule` into import array.

```
imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule]
```